# I have a question about AlphaStar. Is this the right SE to ask it?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

[AlphaStar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AlphaStar_(software)) is an AI that plays Starcraft 2. I want to know if AlphaStar can play FFA (free-for-all, basically there are 4+ players in the same game and the winner is the last player standing).

Is this question on-topic?

Comment: "Can" in what sense? Is it theoretically possible, is it currently practically possible, can it be engineered by you to do so?

Comment: @Joachim "is it currently practically possible" <--

Answer (score 4):

Our site is *generally* more about questions that relate to [actually playing games](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), however, we do classify Game-specific *utilities* as on-topic:

> - Gameplay strategies and tactics
> - Puzzle solving or obstacle clearing
> - Game mechanics and terminology
> - Plot and characters in games
> - Game-specific hardware and **utilities**

Based on [Merriam-Webster's definition of utility](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/utility), this AI is certainly purposed towards playing a video game and is game-specific, therefore I think the question is on-topic.

If/when you ask your question, you should try to include more information if you can. It would help to show us what research you've done already to try and answer your question.